# SAP Business Object - xlf file extension? General Questions

Tags: pdf

I have a potential client that has a couple of PDFs.  These PDFs have several input boxes and sliders, as you enter info it updates a graph.

The goal is to take these PDFs and make web tools out of them.

Apparently, they were created in SAP Business Object.  I have the original .xlf files but I can't open them.

My hope is I could open these files and get access to the calculations and math behind data and how it effects the graph, so I don't have to start from scratch on the web project.

Can someone tell me if this is possible?

Comment: Can you provide a (link to a) representative sample of those PDFs? Without this, it will not be possible to advice you on this question....